# How to use OGDF library with TikZ 3.0?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I try to compile (via `lualatex`) the following MWE without success.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{ogdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [SugiyamaLayout] { a -- {b,c,d} -- e -- a };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I got this message:

```
! LuaTeX error ...tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/ogdf/library.lua:32: m
odule 'pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script' not found:
    no field package.preload['pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script'
    [oberdiek.luatex.kpse_module_loader]-eroux Search failed
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...tex/generic/pgf/graphdrawing/lua/pgf/gd/ogdf/library.lua:32: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [string "\directlua "]:1: in function 'lookup'
    [string "\directlua "]:1: in function 'pgf_lookup_and_require'
    [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
<argument> ...drawing library '\pgf@temp ' not found}}') end}
                                                   \fi 
l.3 \usegdlibrary{ogdf}
```

So, how to use OGDF library with TikZ 3.0?

Answer (score 12):

Too long for a comment. In Section **34 Graph Drawing Algorithms: The Open Graph Drawing Framework**,
the PGF documentation has a rather discouraging message about this:

> Remark: The integration of the ogdf library is still under
>   construction and the examples in this section are more a
>   proof-of-concept. So, use at your own risk.

and then, a few lines below:

> Since C++ code is compiled and not interpreted (like Lua), in order to
>   use the present library, you need a compiled version of the pgf
>   interface code for the ogdf library (`pgf/gd/ogdf/c/ogdf_script.so`)
>   installed correctly for your particular architecture. This is by no
>   means trivial...

So, in order for those examples to work, you need a compiled version of `pgf/gd/ogdf/c/ogdf_script.so` installed correctly for your particular architecture. How to do that, I wouldn't know... I did a quick search on the web but couldn't find anything really helpful. It really seems to be not a trivial task.

Comment: I compiled the OGDF library and the ogdf_script.so (with dynamic link) on Ubuntu. Now, LuaTeX finds pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script.so and the error message changes but I still can not compile the examples. I will continue my tests...

Answer (score 8):

I was able to compile the example after adding the following line:

```
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
```

so that the complete MWE becomes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{ogdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [SugiyamaLayout] { a -- {b,c,d} -- e -- a };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If there still is a problem, you could check that there are no missing dependencies in the PGF-OGDF interface library:

```
ldd PATH_TO/pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script.so
```

The following is a description of what *worked for me* on Ubuntu 12.04 x86-64.

I used the following software / library versions:

- PGF 3.0.0
- [OGDF](http://www.ogdf.net/ogdf.php) v. 2012.07
- Lua 5.2.3

## Installation

### Lua and OGDF

I installed Lua and OGDF from source to a personal, i.e. non-system
directory. I followed the standard procedure,
except for two adjustment to OGDF:

1. Adjusted a parameter in makeMakefile.config:

   ```
   sharedLib = true
   ```
2. Removed `-DOGDF_DLL` from compiler options in makeMakefile.py. In the diff below,
   "<" is the original version and ">" the adjusted version:

   ```
   85c85
   <       compiler = ' '.join( [compiler, '-DOGDF_DLL -DOGDF_INSTALL' ] )
   ---
   >       compiler = ' '.join( [compiler, '-DOGDF_INSTALL' ] )
   ```

### OGDF interface of PGF

I downloaded and unzipped the TDS archive of PGF from
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf .

I created a text file
`source/generic/pgf/c/config/LocalMakefileConfig.mk` with the
following contents:

```
LUAINCLUDES=<LUAPATH>
OGDFINCLUDES=<OGDFPATH>
INSTALLDIR=<TEXBIN>/lib/luatex/lua
MYCFLAGS=-fPIC
```

Note that `<...>` must be replaced with the appropriate values:

- `<LUAPATH>`, path to lua headers
- `<OGDFPATH>`, path to OGDF headers
- `<TEXBIN>`, path to TeX binaries

Alas, I could not find a way to make a local config file that would
allow a simple `make all` to complete (because of the order of
compiler options in the Makefiles). This left me with two
alternatives: edit the Makefiles or compile by hand. I took the latter
route.

I ran the following sequence of commands, where `<LIBPATH>` denotes the
location of the Lua and OGDF libraries (`.so`). Replace it with the
appropriate path. Note that `-L<LIBPATH>` and `-rpath=<LIBPATH>` are not
needed if the libraries have been installed in a standard
location. The idea is basically the following:

1. `make all`
2. if (when) there is an error, fix by hand (create a shared object, `.so`)
3. if there are other `.so` files to be made, go to 1

The command sequence:

```
cd source/generic/pgf/c
make all
cd graphdrawing/pgf/gd/examples/c
gcc -shared SimpleDemoC.o ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC.o \
  -L<LIBPATH> -Wl,--no-undefined,-rpath=<LIBPATH> \
  -lm -llua -o SimpleDemoC.so
cd ../../../../..
make all
cd graphdrawing/pgf/gd/examples/c
g++ -shared SimpleDemoCPlusPlus.o ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC++.o \
  ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC.o -L<LIBPATH> \
  -Wl,--no-undefined,-rpath=<LIBPATH> -llua \
  -o SimpleDemoCPlusPlus.so
cd ../../../../..
make all
cd graphdrawing/pgf/gd/ogdf/c
g++ -shared ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC.o \
  ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC++.o InterfaceFromOGDF.o ogdf_script.o \
  -L<LIBPATH> -Wl,--no-undefined,-rpath=<LIBPATH> \
  -pthread -llua -lOGDF -o ogdf_script.so
cd ../../../../..
make all
cd graphdrawing/pgf/gd/ogdf/c
g++ -shared SimpleDemoOGDF.o ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC++.o \
  ../../interface/c/InterfaceFromC.o InterfaceFromOGDF.o \
  -L<LIBPATH> -Wl,--no-undefined,-rpath=<LIBPATH> \
  -pthread -llua -lOGDF -o SimpleDemoOGDF.so
cd ../../../../..
make install_all
```

After this, TikZ/PGF should be ready to use the OGDF library.

Comment: Interesting... How did you compile pgf_gd_ogdf_c_ogdf_script.so?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how I compiled the interface and also added a few words about building the OGDF library.