# Rebuilding TikZ's pgfmanual.pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, paper-size, documentation

The following steps to rebuild TikZ's pgfmanual.pdf fail on Windows 7 64 bit using MikTex and bash shell:

```
  1) cp -iar /c/opt/miktex_2.9/doc/generic/pgf  .
  2) cd  pgf/version-for-luatex/en
  3) Modify line 10 in both files pgfmanual-test.tex
     and pgfmanual.tex so that it becomes:

      \documentclass[letterpaper]{ltxdoc}

  4) mkdir plots
  5) make
  6) The command "grep gnuplot *log" shows lines such as:

     runsystem(gnuplot plots/pgf-x.gnuplot)...disabled.

  7) Run gnuplot on each of the 8 files in plots/*gnuplot,
     which results in 8 files plots/*table

  8) make; make; make; make

     The last make reports that there was nothing to do for 'all'.
```

However,

1. Page size continues to be A4 (rather than letter)
2. Built document has only 1142 A4 pages (pre-built manual has 1165 A4 pages)

So question:  how to build the TikZ manual in letter size with all the information present?

Comment: I hev not seen the source but this may be caused due to wrong options to the geometry package.

Comment: About the 1165 A4 pages, read [How to use OGDF library with TikZ 3.0?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163343).